# Enum number to string in React component

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript, enums

I have an ASP.NET Core project, and I am using React.

C# Entity:

```
public class Waybill: IEntity
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public WayBillType WayBillType { get; set; }    
}

public enum WayBillType
{
    Moving = 1,
    Incoming = 2,
    Disposal  = 3
}
```

And typescript entity:

```
export class Waybill
{
    id: number;
    wayBillType: WayBillType;
}

enum WayBillType
{
    Moving = 1,
    Incoming = 2,
    Outgoing = 3
}
```

How can I get the string "Moving" instead of "1" within my React component?

Comment: In typescript you can just: `WayBillType[WayBillType.Moving]`

Comment: @AlekseyL. I need number value also, because I have enum with values '{"": 1, "": 2, "":3, "": 99}'.
"" - it's  text

Comment: Number is available as well `WayBillType.Moving`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `JsonConverter` attribute and pass it the [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) of `Newtonsoft.Json.Converters`.:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum WayBillType
{
    Moving = 1,
    Incoming = 2,
    Disposal = 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [tagged union type](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/11/03/typescript-2-0-tagged-union-types) instead of enum:

```
type WayBillType = "Moving" | "Incoming" | "Outgoing";
```

If you care for actual integer values, you could use [index signature](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/03/03/typescript-2-2-dotted-properties-and-string-index-signatures) to build something dictionary-like object and keep mappings in it:

```
interface WayBillTypeMap {
    [key: WayBillType]: int
}
```